# Download a file from other domain(Azure Blob or Amazon S3) from React app?

Tags: reactjs, download, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to download files from the client web page after user action is performed(download button click), how can I do that?

I want to have similar experience to that of downloading a file from Google Drive.

Currently, I can download the file after the user clicks save(primary action) of the finder(file explorer). - *This is the overhead I'm trying to remove.*

I tried having plan  tag with download prop and also using fetch & then creating  tag from js with createObjectURL, but two I'm unable to remove additional native confirmation before downloading the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this without the extra native confirmation, you can try using  JavaScript to trigger the dwnload. i suggest using the Blob and URL.createObjectURL approach.
for your ref see below-

```html
<!-- Your download button -->
<button id="downloadButton">Download File</button>

<!-- Your script -->
<script>
  document.getElementById('downloadButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
    // Assume 'fileData' is your file data, replace it with your actual data
    const fileData = 'Hello, this is your file content!';
    const blob = new Blob([fileData], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = url;
    a.download = 'your_file_name.txt'; // Set your desired file name
    a.style.display = 'none';

    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();

    // Clean up
    document.body.removeChild(a);
    URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  });
</script>
```